# Playig EasyMovieTexture with huge 360°Videos

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, video

i use the Unity3D-Asset "EasyMovieTexture" for showing 360-Videos in a sphere and want to build it as an app for Android.

I stream it from the local SD-Card without saving it to my persistent datapath of the app (like it is in the demo-function).

Problem:
Videos which are bigger than 500MB let my app crashing. Is it possible to stream (local) bigger Videos by adding some functionality? Or is it a "border" in my device? I devided my videos in smaller pieces but its not the best solution for my application...

Everything else is working fine...

By the way:
The normal Unity Videoplayer is not a practical solution for me because it is very jerky. So i decided to use EasyMovieTexture.

It would be very nice, if anyone has an info for me.

Device:

Android 7.0, 
Samsung S6

In the following piece of Code the App crashes, when i try to "load" (eq stream) a videofile with a size bigger than 1GB

```
    // Own Class
    public MediaPlayerCtrl mediaPlayerCtrl;
    private string VIDEO_PLAYLIST_01 = "xyz";

    // delegeate for changing video file in lifetime
    public void onVideoChange(object _video) {

       int number = (int)_video;
       string[] temp = (Application.persistentDataPath.Replace("Android", "")).Split(new string[] { "//" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);

       // stop latest video     
       mediaPlayerCtrl.Stop();
       mediaPlayerCtrl.m_strFileName = null;
       mediaPlayerCtrl.m_bLoop = false;

       switch (number) {

       case 1:

          if (File.Exists(temp[0] + "/Download/" +  VIDEO_PLAYLIST_01 + ".mp4")) {
             // if file found load the stream of it with easymovietexturectrol
             StartCoroutine(openStream(VIDEO_PLAYLIST_01));
          } else {
             Application.Quit();
          }
       break;

       default: 
          break;
       }
     }

     IEnumerator openStream(string vid) {
        mediaPlayerCtrl.OnVideoFirstFrameReady += firstFrameReady;
        // wait until stream loaded        
        yield return StartCoroutine(mediaPlayerCtrl.StreamVideoFromPath("file://" + temp[0] + "/Download/" + vid + ".mp4"));
     }
```

---

```
// Class of Easy Movie Texture - MoviePlayerCtrl 
// i used the "DownloadStreamingVideoAndLoad2" before and then it crashes cause
// this class load a fully bytefile of the video in the persistent path. my class 
//only loads things by using the www-class 

public IEnumerator StreamVideoFromPath(string strURL) {

    strURL = strURL.Trim();

    WWW www = new WWW(strURL);
    yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error)) {
       Load("file://" + strURL);
       Debug.Log(strURL);
    } else {                
       Debug.Log(www.error);
       Application.Quit();
    }

    www.Dispose();
    www = null;
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
}
```

Comment: It seems possible. Post the current code you have that is crashing due to the file size. Also add C# tag to your question.

Comment: i commented my code as an edit of the original question. my videofiles are bigger than 1.3GB. Maybe its a general problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem: Don´t use the WWW-Class for streaming a mp4-File from your sd-card. Only use the Load("file://" + strURL) in the Coroutine. It streams a 3GB videofile very smart on my 3D-Sphere-Texture.

```
public IEnumerator StreamVideoFromPathWithoutLoadingItIntoMemory(string strURL) {

    strURL = strURL.Trim();
    Load("file://" + strURL);

    Debug.Log(strURL);
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
}
```